# Determine current branch / commit id

Tags: git, cron, openshift

*To clarify, this question relates to an Openshift installation.*

I'm trying to write a cron script that checks every now and again for changes made to the site (it's a CMS so changes may be either to the database or the files, but my scripts already handle that). If it finds a change, it should commit these changes to the git repo.

This works fine if I assume that I'm on the `master` branch. However it'd be nice to be able to check out development branches and have any auto-commits sent to these branches rather than echoed back to the master, overwriting it.

**How can I detect within the cron script which is the current branch and so where new commits should be sent?**

Comment: The output of [`git status`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-status) starts with the current branch.

Comment: Uh huh but the `repo` folder isn't actually a git repo: it's only the contents of the latest commit. The git repo itself lives in `~/git` but it's a bare repo which, iirc, means that it doesn't have a HEAD pointer

Comment: Your question is not clear. You want to commit but you don't have a regular repository, just a snapshot of its files and a bare repository. Where do you want to commit? Directly in the bare repository?

Comment: Since this is an automatic process, I suggest you create a branch for this purpose. Make the cron job always commit to this branch and let the developers review the changes and integrate them into the master branch manually. This way it won't overwrite anybody's work.

Comment: Sorry, this was meant to be tagged as relating to Openshift. I've added that now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try looking in your `~/app-deployments/current` directory and check out the contents of the `metadata.json` file, there you will find the following information that describes the current deployment.

```
{
"git_ref":"master",
"git_sha1":"d73e396",
"id":"ad01e23d",
"hot_deploy":null,
"force_clean_build":null,
"activations":[1456247028.9351604],
"checksum":"2d041cdb9042ac3f3e3a8f067ad8c583e2a22123"
}
```

If you have multiple deployments setup (as referenced here: https://developers.openshift.com/en/managing-deployments.html) then each deployment that is kept around should have this same information available.  You also need to be aware that if you are running a scaled application, this information is probably only available on the head gear (the one running haproxy, and that hosts your git repository).

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for, perfect, thank you!